# How can use 15 px, #000000 7 % opacity to #000000 0 % opacity in box shadow?

Tags: html, css

I'm new in `css` and `html` and want to implant this box shadow with this plan?

```
 Box shadow: 15 px, #000000 7 % opacity to #000000 0 % opacity
```

for that purpose write this css:

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) #dadada;
```

but that not my purpose output.How can i write css for that?thanks all.

Comment: So you want to have a gradient in your box-shadow color?

Comment: @Sebastian Yes i want my friend.

Comment: What's the problem with `box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);`?

Comment: Can we see a picture of the actual output that you want? A normal box-shadow will go from the color you have specified (alpha = 0.7) to alpha = 0. (By the way, alpha = 0.7 is **not** 7% opacity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this result with pseudoelements and `linear-gradient`, like this

```css
body{
  background-color:wheat;
}
#demo{
  position: relative;
  margin:20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color:aqua;
}
#demo:before{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;  
  left:-15px;
  top:-15px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```